# Changing the background color of a table row (jsfiddle)

Tags: jquery

I generated a table demo of something similar to what I have on my website. The idea is that every row cell contains small image, clicking on an image generates a popup with corresponding information about the small image that was clicked. I am trying to modify my jquery so that the popup that is open makes the row (that is belongs to) background change, so it easy to track which row the popup belongs to.

See jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WL9tS/

Comment: $(e.target).closest("#favorites-table tr").css({'background-color':'#000000'}); this change row background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this line to the click event:

```
$(this).parent().parent().css("background-color","#CCC");
```

then just figure out a way to return it to its original color when done.